# Android: Publishing app on play store without a domain name

Tags: android

I want to ask how to give a package name to my app if i don't have a domain . Say my app name is "Hello World" , i want to ask what should be the package name .

Furthermore if i upload my app on play store is it possible that anyone else can download my app and upload that app from his account and start making money ?? can't i do anything about it ?

How can i claim copyrights on my app ? If some one steal my app and i don't have copyrights then what can i do in that case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I want to ask how to give a package name to my app if i don't have a domain .
Say my app name is "Hello World" , i want to ask what should be the package name .
```

If you don't have domain then use yours name or something else unique. The important part is that the domain is unique so that you avoid clashes, and not that it starts with a real Internet top-level domain like org or com.

```
How can i claim copyrights on my app ?
```

for this go through [this](http://www.hedgesappdev.com/2012/08/do-i-need-to-copyright-my-app-or-is-it-already-copyrighted/)

Comment: So should i register my copyright or my app is automatically copyright to me ?

Comment: Google Play offers a licensing service that lets you enforce licensing policies for applications that you publish on Google Play. With Google Play Licensing, your application can query Google Play at run time to obtain the licensing status for the current user, then allow or disallow further use as appropriate.
you can read this here [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html)

Comment: If you are using login from Gmail or other it matches the SHA1 key which is specified and can only change by you.
 i just can't give yes or no exactly answer, its totally your choice 

yes you can copyright your app, it will help you but even after copyright anyone can take the idea of your app and create new one.

No there is no such need as you register your app from your specified account.

Comment: thank you so much ... i got my answer :)